# Convert array of eight bytes to eight integers

Tags: x86, avx2, xeon-phi, avx512, knights-landing

I am working with the Xeon Phi Knights Landing. I need to do a gather operation from an array of doubles.  The list of indices comes from an array of chars. The gather operations are either `_mm512_i32gather_pd` or `_mm512_i64gather_pd`. As I understand it, I either need to convert eight chars to to eight 32-bit integers or eight chars to 64-bit integers. I have gone with the first choice for `_mm512_i32gather_pd`.

I have created two functions `get_index` and `get_index2` to convert eight chars to a `__m256i`.  The assembly for `get_index` is simpler than for `get_index2` see https://godbolt.org/z/lhg9fX. However, in my code `get_index2` is significantly faster. **Why is this?** I am using ICC 18. Maybe there is a better solution than either of these two functions?

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

__m256i get_index(char *index) {                                                                                                                                      
  int64_t x = *(int64_t *)&index[0];                                                                                                                                             
  const __m256i t3 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    1,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    2,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    3,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    4,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    5,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    6,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    7,0x80,0x80,0x80);                                                                                                                                                     

  __m256i t2 = _mm256_set1_epi64x(x);                                                                                                                                            
  __m256i t4 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(t2, t3);                                                                                                                                      
  return t4;                                                                                                                                                                     
}                

__m256i get_index2(char *index) {
  const __m256i t3 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    1,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    2,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    3,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    4,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    5,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    6,0x80,0x80,0x80,
    7,0x80,0x80,0x80);
  __m128i t1  = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)index);
  __m256i t2 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(t1), t1, 1);
  __m256i t4 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(t2, t3);
  return t4;
}
```

Comment: KNL has *very* slow 256-bit `vpshufb ymm` (12 uops, 23c latency, 12c throughput), and 128-bit XMM is slow, too.  (MMX is fast :P).  See Agner Fog's tables.  Why can't you use [`vpmovzxbd` or `bq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMOVZX.html) like a normal person?   `__m512i _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(__m128i a)` or `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32`.  Those are all single-uop with 2c throughput.

Comment: That doesn't explain your results, though.  What loop did these functions inline into?  Are you sure they didn't optimize differently somehow given different surrounding code?  Otherwise IDK why a load + insert would be faster than a qword broadcast-load.  Maybe some kind of front-end effect?  Again we'd need to see the whole loop to guess about the front-end.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you for pointing out `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32`, that's exactly what I want, the result is no faster than `get_index2` though in my code. Maybe ICC converts `get_index2` to vpmovzxbd in my code anyway. I did not think of this because I'm a bit rusty with vectorization. But now I get about a 4x improvement with manual vectorization compare to ICC auto-vectorization (with `#pragma ivdep`). I'm vectorizing [stencil code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code).